# Bash illegal number error in return statement

Tags: bash, function, shell, syntax

I am trying to call a bash function and assign the output the function returns to a variable. However, when I run the code below, I get the following error and I don't understand what I may be doing wrong:

`test.sh: return: line 7: Illegal number: aGVsbG93b3JsZA==
helloworld`

```
convertfrombase64 () {
  B64DATA=$1
  echo "$B64DATA" | base64 -d
  return "$B64DATA"
}

PLAINTEXT=$(convertfrombase64 "aGVsbG93b3JsZA==")
echo "$PLAINTEXT"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't return a string from a function. A Bash function's return value follows the same rules as that of exit codes - see the related post.

You are already using the output of the function correctly. May be you want to return the exit code of `base64` to indicate status, this way:

```
convertfrombase64 () {
  B64DATA=$1
  echo "$B64DATA" | base64 -d
  return $?
}
```

Based on the great suggestions got from comments, the above function could be better written as:

```
convertfrombase64() {
  printf '%s' "$1" | base64 -d
}
```

---

See this post for more details:

- [Returning a value from a Bash function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90724/returning-a-value-from-a-bash-function)

Comment: Thank works thanks. Turns out I don't need to return anything, just want the value.

Comment: +1. Note that `return $?` is actually redundant, since the default behavior is to return the exit status of the last command. In fact, the function could written as just `convertfrombase64 () { base64 -d <<< "$1" ; }`, which also avoids touching the global `B64DATA` variable, avoids any nontrivial behaviors of `echo`, avoids some unnecessary subshells, etc.

Comment: You probably want `printf '%s' "$1" | base64 -d` instead of the here string, which will add a trailing newline to the value being decoded.